# Firefox addon hangs while loading multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have an addon which loads multiple URLs in tab format. For URLs of certain websites, it is being seen that it hangs while loading. When I try to load the same URLs on firefox browser, it doesn't hang.

Need help. Why may firefox behave differently in addon case? Sample code here:

```
function addTabsForCounter(tabCounter) {
var tabHtml = $("<tab>").attr("onclick", "showTab(" + tabCounter + ")").attr("id", "tab_button" + tabCounter).attr("style", "width:140px;").attr("crop", "right").attr("label", "TAB " + (tabCounter+1));
$("#all_tabs").append(tabHtml);

var view = $("<browser>").attr("id", "view" + tabCounter).attr("type", "content-targetable").attr("src", "").attr("showcaret", "true").attr("flex", "100").attr("tooltip", "browserTooltip");
var mView = $("<label>").attr("id", "view_meta" + tabCounter).attr("style", "display: none;");

if(tabCounter === 0) {
    $("#tabbox_outer_hbox").after(view);
    $("#view0").after(mView);
} else {
    var prev = (tabCounter-1);
    $("#view" + prev).after(view);
    $("#view_meta" + prev).after(mView);
}

$("#view" + tabCounter).get(0).addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onBrowserDOMContentLoad, true);
$("#view" + tabCounter).get(0).addEventListener("DOMTitleChanged", onBrowserTitleChange, true);
$("#view" + tabCounter).get(0).addEventListener("keypress", onKeyPressInBrowser, true);}




function setupMappingLayout(currenta, currentc, Item, tabCounter) {
Item.startTime = new Date().getTime();

addTabsForCounter(tabCounter);
$("#view_meta" + tabCounter).val(JSON.stringify({
    'asin': currenta,
    'comp': currentc,
    'zipregion' : getRDefault(Item),
    date: " "
}));

refreshCountView();
$("#view" + tabCounter).get(0).loadURI(Item.url);
Item.status = "LOADED";}
```

Note: The original codes variable names have been modified before copying here, please ignore any such errors.

Comment: What [kind of Firefox extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) is this about ([WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) [[tag:firefox-webextensions]],  [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) [[tag:fiirefox-addon-sdk]], [Bootstraped](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) [[tag:firefox-addon-restartless]], or [Overlay/XUL/Legacy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions) [[tag:fiirefox-addon-overlay]])? Please [edit] the *one* appropriate tag into your question.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: It is am XUL based firefox addon. We are calling addTabForCounter before I want to show an URL and setting the URI in the function setupMappingLayout but it fails once I start loading two-there URLs